# Virtualbox gui doesn't work

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

ubuntu 20.04.4 and virtualbox 6.0, I tried with 6.1 too, with the default packages of ubuntu repositories and with .deb

I have the secure boot disabled and I run successfuly /sbin/vboxconfig.

The problem is that when I execute virtualbox the gui shows only this

[image]

And I cannot work with that only.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT**

```
dkms status 
backport-iwlwifi, 8324: added
nvidia, 510.60.02, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.60.02, 5.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.60.02, 5.13.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
uname -r
5.13.0-41-generic
```

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `dkms status` and `uname -r`.

Comment: Please deinstall `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` it not build nor installed in any kernel version. then reinstall your virtualbox packages.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly